# Error en la condicional

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando un código en JavaScript, en donde comprueba si el año el mes y el día es menor a la fecha actual, me muestre un mensaje que ponga correcto, pero si algo no, que me ponga error.

Es decir, si `05/10/22` es menor a `10/03/23`, me muestre correcto.

Tengo hecho esto y me da error:

```js
const fechaActual = new Date();
const añoActual = fechaActual.getFullYear();
const mesActual = fechaActual.getMonth() + 1;
const diaActual = fechaActual.getDate();

var año = 2023;
var mes = 07;
var dia = 20;

if (año <= añoActual) {
  // AÑO ES CORRECTO
  if (mes <= mesActual) {
    // MES ES CORRECTO
    if (dia <= diaActual) {
      // DIA ES CORRECTO
      // TODO ES CORRECTO
      console.log('todo correcto');
    }
  }
} else {
  console.log('La fecha es mayor a la actual');
}
```

Comment: Mencionaste dos veces que tenés un error, pero no olvides [edit] tu pregunta para describir _cuál es el error_.

Comment: El codigo funciona.. obviamente tu forma de comparar fechas es erroneo, y por eso pensas que tiene un error.. simplemente hay rutas de tu codigo, que no devuelven nada....

Comment: Te recomiendo darle una repasada a las sentencias `if` `else` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else tienes un problema lógico en donde si el mes o el dia no son correctos no sucede nada en tu código. Como dicen arriba, si realmente te da un error por favor agrégalo a la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Tienes errores en tus condicionales, tendrías que usar `else if` para indicar que si no cumple con el primer `if`, continua a la siguiente condición de abajo, así hasta llegar al `else`. Con esto, siempre te dará una respuesta, porque si no cumple con uno, va al otro, y así sucesivamente.

```
if (...) {
  return ...
} else if (...) {
  return ...
} else if (...) {
  return ...
} else {
  return ...
}
```

Ahora, recuerda que para verificar si una fecha es menor que la actual, hay que comparar en todos los casos posibles. Aquí estamos verificando al año, mes y día (tus 3 variables) si son menores a la actual. Entonces, se hizo una condicional para todos los casos (explicación en comentarios):

```js
const fechaActual = new Date();
const anioActual = fechaActual.getFullYear();
const mesActual = fechaActual.getMonth() + 1;
const diaActual = fechaActual.getDate();

function verificarFecha(dia, mes, anio) {
  // para el caso que el año ingresado sea menor al actual, todo correcto.
  if (anio < anioActual) {
    return ("todo correcto");
  // para el caso que el año ingresado sea igual al actual pero el mes ingresado es menor al actual, correcto.
  } else if (anio === anioActual && mes < mesActual) {
    return ("todo correcto");
  // para el caso que el año ingresado sea igual al actual, el mes ingresado sea igual actual pero el día ingresado es menor al actual, correcto.
  } else if (anio === anioActual && mes === mesActual && dia <= diaActual) {
    return ("todo correcto");
  // si el día, mes y año ingresado es mayor al dia, mes y año actual, entra al else (ya que no cumpliría con ninguno de los if).
  } else {
    return ("La fecha es mayor a la actual");
  }
}

console.log(verificarFecha(01, 02, 2023)) // ¿La fecha es mayor al actual? => ✔️, Entro a los if
console.log(verificarFecha(20, 06, 2023)) // ¿La fecha es mayor al actual? => ❌, Entro al else
```

Answer (score 0):

Te faltan los `else` por eso no ves los retornos

```js
const fechaActual = new Date();
const añoActual = fechaActual.getFullYear();
const mesActual = fechaActual.getMonth() + 1;
const diaActual = fechaActual.getDate();

var año = 2023;
var mes = 07;
var dia = 20;

if (año <= añoActual) {
  if (mes <= mesActual) {
    if (dia <= diaActual) {
      console.log('todo correcto');
    }
    else{
        console.log('dia incorrecto');
    }
  }
  else{
  console.log('mes incorrecto');
  }
} else {
  console.log('La fecha es mayor a la actual');
}
```

Otra manera de hacerlo, es funcionar directamente con `Date`, para esto tenemos que considerad que cuando haces `new Date()` te entrega la fecha actual pero con horas!!! para quitarlas podemos volver a crear otro `Date` ingresando como argumento solo el año, mes y día, del día actual.

```js
const now = new Date();
const fechaActual = new Date(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth(),now.getDate());
const otrafecha= new Date(2023,1,2);

if(fechaActual>otrafecha){
  console.log("La fecha es mayor a la actual");
}
else if(fechaActual<otrafecha){
  console.log("La fecha es menor a la actual");
}
else{
  console.log("La fecha es igual a la actual");
}
```